# infinite mape is $k-$colourable if and only if each finite subset of the map is $k-$colourable

Tags: logic

Prove:

An infinite map is $k-$colourable if and only if  each finite subset of the map is $k-$colourable .

How to use compactness theorem at this problem?
And the compactness theorem says that $\sum$ has a model if and only if the every finite subset of $\sum$ has a model.

For this problem how to define $\sum$ and language?

Answer (score 1):

You need a binary relation $A$; the intended interpretation of $A(x,y)$ is that regions $x$ and $y$ are adjacent. You need a constant for each region, so that you can specify in your theory which regions are adjacent. You need a way to specify a $k$-coloring. There are several ways to do this; one is to have unary relations $C_1,\ldots,C_k$ and sentences specifying that for each region $x$, exactly one of $C_1(x),\ldots,C_k(x)$ holds. Finally, you’ll need a sentence specifying that adjacent regions don’t have the same color.

Comment: Don't you also need a name for each of the regions? (Personally I'd skip the logic and just use the ultrafilter or Tychonoff directly, but the question leaves no choice; I guess this is an exercise from logic course.)

Comment: @bof: Yes, it appears that I somehow forgot to specify the map itself; thanks for the reminder. (I also tend to use the ultrafilter or Tikhonov directly.)